# What results sources the KQL will use in default?

Tags: search-results

In site collection, we can configure to target specific result sources to use in search page (top-right corner search box). However, which result sources will be user in KQL? will it inherit site collection setting?

Answer (score 1):

The Default Result Source will be used when a specific Result Source is not identified. Look in Settings | Search Result Sources.

Comment: So, when i specific a result source in a site collection, KQL will automatically use that result source?

Comment: If you mark it as default, yes. The way to check is to look at the result source in use by the Search Result web part. If you are using the API it will use the default.